# Add a tag to an existing contact using the Mautic API

Tags: mautic

I've been driving myself crazy for days trying to figure it out.

When I search "tags" in the [docs](https://developer.mautic.org/#edit-tag), the only results seem to relate to creating and editing the tag records themselves rather than any association to a contact's record.

I see this [test class](https://github.com/mautic/api-library/blob/879324bfff244929c53bd97fec3b06e2ab771769/tests/Api/ContactsTest.php#L31-L34) linked from [this issue](https://github.com/mautic/api-library/issues/116) but don't understand since there isn't actual documentation or a simple example of how to use the API to add a tag to a contact.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
'tags' => ['tag1', 'tag2']
```

P.S. That test class code seems to be for creating a *new* contact with certain tags, when instead what I want to do is associate an existing tag with an existing contact.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same payload for create and update as well.

Endpoint: `PATCH api/contacts/ID/edit`

With data: `tags[0]=tagA`
which will URL decode to: `tags%5B0%5D=tagA`

Or you can use JSON format for the data payload if you specify it in the header (`'Content-Type: application/json'`):

```
{
    "tags": ["tagA"]
}
```

The request is containing the tag like this:

```
{
  "contact": {
    ...
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": 32,
        "tag": "tagA"
      }
    ],
   ...
}
```